Quarkus @ConfigProperty does not inject value
I am using quarkus @ConfigProperty annotation in order to inject value to a String data member:
@ApplicationScoped
public class ActiveMQRout extends RouteBuilder {

    public String getOrderMessage() {
        return orderMessage;
    }
    public void setOrderMessage(String orderMessage) {
        this.orderMessage = orderMessage;
    }
    
    @ConfigProperty(name="order")
    String orderMessage;

//more code that uses orderMessage
}

In application.properties file I have this value:
order=order2
the value of orderMessage stay null. I have tried using the following option instead of injection:
orderMessage = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("order", String.class);
and it is working. how can I make this work with injection (by using @ConfigProperty annotation)?
(I have tried using the @Singleton annotation for the class ActiveMQRout but still did not work.
I also added getter and setter but still did not work)

How are you instantiating the ActiveMQRout class? You need to let the CDI container create an instance. Creating an instance manually, using new ActiveMQRout(), will not inject the dependencies (or provide any other container services).

How should I instantiate the ActiveMQRout class in this case?

@Naamabe you shouldn't. CDI should create the bean (this is what @ApplicationScoped - among other things - is for. Can you post a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository? I have multiple applications that do pretty much what you do, and they work as expected

I  had the same problem because I was using the config property in the constructor, but it's often not set yet when the constructor is called.
I used @PostConstruct to use the config property and then it was not null anymore.
// THIS WORKS: Using the prop in a @PostConstruct method

@ApplicationScoped
public class BookRepository {

private final Set<Book> books = //...

@ConfigProperty(name = "books.genre")
String genre;

@PostConstruct
void init() {
    books.add(new Book(1, "The Great Gatsby", "F. Scott Fitzgerald", 1925, genre));
    books.add(new Book(2, "To Kill a Mockingbird", "Harper Lee", 1960, genre));
    books.add(new Book(3, "1984", "George Orwell", 1949, genre));
}

So be careful WHEN you call the property, because it might not contain its value yet.
